# I don't use contact permission in manifest file. But I am getting contact permission in app info screen

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, manifest

I don't use contact permission in manifest file. But i am getting contact permission in app info screen.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: put the code of your MainActivity or where you are working

Comment: I don't understand why it is asking for contact permission.

try to remove this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
` and then check.

Answer (score 5):

Android uses groups of permissions instead of single permission when asking the user to grand them.

You use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

which is in **Contacts** group.

This is the reason why you see _Contacts__ permission in app info screen.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html

> The dialog does not describe the specific permission within that
>   group. For example, if an app requests the READ_CONTACTS permission,
>   the system dialog just says the app needs access to the device's
>   contacts

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following permission from android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

it will solve your problem